# Seaborn not showing full plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot the "Tips" dataset from the Seaborn library, but when doing so I am only getting the dark background of the chart. The actual scatter plot and histogram along the edges are not showing.

I am running the code inside Spyder from the Anaconda distribution.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt

sns.set(style="darkgrid", color_codes=True)


#Import data
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.head()

sns.jointplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data='tips')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `data="tips"` is not a `string`

so you need to change the following line:

```
sns.jointplot(x='total_bill', y='tip', data=tips)
```